# auto fill records using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

i have these jquery code that will fetch the data on database on user focus out then fill the html inputs. the problem is when i have this multiple row and yet the only row that is being filled is the first row any help? please see code below.

```
$("input[id^='p_code']").focusin(function() {
    var thisid = $(this).attr("id");
    $(document).on('focusout', "input[id='" + thisid + "']", function() {
        var prodappend = $("input[id='" + thisid + "']").val();
        var prodprepend = padDigitss(prodappend, 8);
        $("input[id='" + thisid + "']").val(prodprepend);
        var searchVal = $(this).val();

        if (searchVal !== '') {
            var count1 = counts + 1;
            $.get('functions/prodquery.php?page=purchaseorder&ctr=' + count1 + '&searchData=' + searchVal, function(returnData) {
                if (!returnData) {
                    $('#showld').html('<p style="padding:5px;">Search term entered does not return any data.</p>');
                } else {
                    $('#showld').html(returnData);

                    var prdname = $("input[id^='prdname']").val();
                    var prdunit = $("input[id^='prdunit']").val();
                    var prdunit2 = $("input[id^='produnit']").val();
                    var prdcost = $("input[id^='prdcost']").val();
                    var secondcost = $("input[id^='secondcost']").val();
                    var bcode = $("input[id^='bcode']").val();

                    $("input[id=barcode" + counts + "]").val(bcode);
                    $("input[id=units" + counts + "]").val(prdunit);
                    $("input[id=ucost" + counts + "]").val(prdcost);
                    $("input[id=p_name" + counts + "]").val(prdname);
                    $('select').append('<option value="' + prdcost + '">' + prdunit + '</option><option value="' + secondcost + '">' + prdunit2 + '</option>');
                    $("select[id=units" + counts + "]").change(function() {
                        var sval = $(this).val();
                        var tval = $("select[id=units" + counts + "]").find('option:selected').text();
                        $("input[id=utexts" + counts + "]").val(tval);
                        $("input[id=ucost" + counts + "]").val(sval);
                        var q_ty = $("input[id=qty" + counts + "]").val();
                        var amt = (parseFloat(q_ty) * parseFloat(sval));
                        $("input[id=amts" + counts + "]").val(amt);
                    });
                    $(document).on("focusout", "input[id=qty" + counts + "]", function() {
                        var q_ty = $("input[id=qty" + counts + "]").val();
                        var amts = (parseFloat(q_ty) * parseFloat(prdcost));
                        $("input[id=amts" + counts + "]").val(amts);
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    });
});
```

BELOW IS MY HTML CODE WITH PHP CODE WITH THE TEXT BOX TO BE FILLED WHEN THE USER FOCUS OUT.

```
    <table id="rredit" class="table table-bordered table-striped  hover cell-border compact stripe">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="10%" id="head">Bar Code</th>
        <th width="10%" id="head">Product Code</th>
        <th width="15%" id="head">Lot No.</th>
        <th width="3%" id="head"></th>
        <th width="9%" id="head">Expiry Date</th>
        <th width="20%" id="head">Poduct Description</th>
        <th width="8%" id="head">Qty</th>
        <th width="10%" id="head">Unit</th>
        <th width="20%" id="head">Cost</th>
        <th width="20%" id="head">Amount</th>
        <th width="10%" id="head">Delete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
while($rowrritem = sqlsrv_fetch_array($populatepoitem)){ $ctr= $ctr+1;?>
    <tr>
        <td><input size="14px" id="barcode<?php echo $ctr;?>" name="barcode[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $rowrritem['barcode']; ?> "></td>
        <td><input size="6px" id="p_code<?php echo $ctr;?>" class="lew" name="p_code[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $rowrritem['product_code']; ?> "></td>
        <td align="center"><input size="15px;" id="lot_no<?php echo $ctr;?>" name="lot_no[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $rowrritem['lot_no']; ?> "></td>
        <td><a href="#ldModal" role="button" class="ld<?php echo $ctr;?>" id="<?php echo $rowrritem['product_code']; ?> " data-toggle="modal"><img src="images/new.png" width="30px" height="28px"></a></td>
        <td align="center"><input size="6px" id="exp_date<?php echo $ctr;?>" name="exp_date[]" type="text" value="<?php if($rowrritem['exp_date'] !== null){ echo date_format($rowrritem['exp_date'], "Y-m-d");} ?> "></td>
        <td><input id="p_name<?php echo $ctr;?>" disabled="" name="p_name[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $rowrritem['prod_name']; ?> "></td>
        <td align="center"><input size="3px" id="qty<?php echo $ctr;?>" name="qty[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $rowrritem['qty']; ?> "></td>
        <td align="center"><select name="unit[]" id="units<?php echo $ctr;?>"><option value="<?php echo $rowrritem['stdcost'];?>"><?php echo $rowrritem['unit1'];?></option><option value="<?php echo $rowrritem['stdcost2'];?>"><?php echo $rowrritem['unit2'];?></option></select></td>
        <td align="center"><input size="4px" id="ucost<?php echo $ctr;?>" name="ucost[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $rowrritem['cost']; ?> "></td>
        <td><input size="5px" id="amts<?php echo $ctr;?>" readonly name="amts[]" type="text" value="<?php echo $rowrritem['qty'] * $rowrritem['cost'];?>" ></td>
        <td align="center"><a href="#" name="delete" id="del" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: have you tried implementing it through classes instead? so that you could apply it in multiple instances of input tags

Comment: yes but it does the same only the first row is the one that is being filled. you have any sample script?